How to allow multiple sub-domains in a self-signed certificate
Context
I have two servers:

a web site at web.example.com (served by a apache2 server configured with a self-signed certificate).
a REST server at api.example.com (served by a Python3 HTTP server configured with a self-signed certificate).

The web site periodically queries the REST api to populate the home page.
They both share the same Root CA and their validity duration give a few more months.
Problem
When I connect to web.example.com from my browser for the first time, it notifies me for potentially un-trusted connection and asks me to accept the risk to continue, which I do. There's no surprise here because I rely on self-signed certificates.
However, this only works for web.example.com. I mean that it seems that the requests to api.example.com are somehow filtered out ; The queries raise a NetworkError exception.
In order to make this work, I have to also open my browser to api.example.com and say that I accept the risk for that domain too. Then I go back to web.example.com and things go smooth! This is not a practical solution to me ..
Question
How can I make the browser accept the requests to the other sub-domain(s) without having to manually accept the risk for each?
NOTES:

I would like the solution to also function on mobile devices.
I do not want to buy a certificate signed by a trusted authority.

